# List of EditText in Android not working

Tags: java, android

I have these 2 arrays of strings:

```
List <String> cuvinte_introduse=new ArrayList<String>();
List <String> cuvinte_bune=new ArrayList<String>();
```

And, I used them like this:

```
cuvinte_introduse.add(cuv1.getText().toString());
cuvinte_bune.add("cuvant1")
```

where `cuv1` is an `EditText`
But then, here :

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int contor=0;
        for(int i=0;i<cuvinte_bune.size();i++) {
            if((cuvinte_bune.get(i)).equals(cuvinte_introduse.get(i))) {
                contor++;
            }
            txt.setText(contor+" puncte");
        }
    }
});
```

`cuv1.getText().toStrings()` gives me the right value, but `cuvinte_introduse.get(i)` does not and I have no idea why.

Comment: nothing...like a never added something, but if I change cuvinte_introduse.add(cuv1.getText().toString()); to cuvinte_introduse.add("something"); then this is visible

Comment: When are are you executing `cuvinte_introduse.add(cuv1.getText().toString()); cuvinte_bune.add("cuvant1")` these statements? As in at which event?

Comment: After this lines of code: `@Override                                                                                 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.joc_curs); `

Comment: You're sure cuv1 has its text set when you call if((cuvinte_bune.get(i)).equals(cuvinte_introduse.get(i)))? Looks like cuv1's text value is empty. Try settings it value in the XML layout first and see if your code works.

Comment: @user5642508 At that point, EditText wouldn't have any value and it will give you blank. Try to add the same inside the onClick method.